# Is there a web interface for the email groups capability exposed via Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

Is there a web interface for the email groups capability exposed via Google Apps, since we would like to have the capability to search later on? We are probably on the starter edition of Google Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
http://groups.google.com/a/<your-domain-name>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for us, the site just keeps loading or throws a weird error. Is this part of the standard edition or we need to pay for this service.

Comment: Google

500. That’s an error.

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it. That’s all we know.

Comment: You don't need to pay the service. @priya

Comment: Not sure why it is failing for me consistently, if its not a paid service.

Comment: What's the URL you're accessing it at @priya?

Comment: Looks like I would need Google Business edition for this to be functional. But I would like to enable only Groups and not other services from Google. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The web interface for groups (Forums) is not available on the free version. See [the Google Apps pricing page](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html) and then click "Compare more features". You will see that while "Mailing lists" are included in the free version, "User-managed forums and mailing lists" are not.